Need some help with xymatrix
I was wondering if someone could help me with the following from representation:
My code is
\[\xymatrix{FG\times U\xrightarrow{\phi} U \ar@/^0.5pc/[r]\ar@/_0.5pc/[r]&G\times U\xrightarrow{\varphi}U}\]

I want the bottom arrow to go left (but I get an error when I replace [r] with [l]).

Well ... your posted code can't compile. Sounds like a question quickly being closed to me ...

To go to left there should be a cell on the left of its cell. So, if you have two cells only, the left arrow should start from the second cell, that is, after the column separator & symbol.

@Sigur But this gives me <--> and It's not what I want.

@PietroP, sorry. It is not clear what you want. Try to add a picture.

I've just edited the code.

(not at pc). It is doable in xy, but probably much easier in tikxcd. As others have mentioned probably don't do both arrows from the same cell. Also the xrightarrow ought to be a proper xy arrow, then the code will be easier to understand. I still find tikxcd easier to work with

So, you need 4 cells. Right arrow from the 1st, 2nd and 3rd cells. Left arrow from the 3rd cell.

Thanks, I got it.

As mentioned, maybe tikzcd is better than xy. Observe that, since the 2nd and 3rd cell contents have different widths, the curved arrow overlap it, because they go to center of the cell by default.
\[
 \xymatrix{
      FG \times U \ar[r]^-{\phi}
    & U           \ar@/^0.5cm/[r]
    & G  \times U \ar@/^0.5cm/[l] \ar[r]^-{\varphi}
    & U
 }
\]



Thanks very much.
